# *ngFor doesn't display data at all

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm new to Angular and trying to create a simple webapp. In my code I use *ngFor to generate some input boxes, but nothing shows up. I've tried dumbing my code down and it still doesn't work!

Here is some simple code that I tried:

**Component.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { ParentComponent} from "./ParentComponent/ParentComponent.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './Component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Component.component.css']
})

export class Component extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private numbers : string[] = ['1', '2', '3'];

  constructor() { 
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.numbers);
    this.formElement = document.getElementById('form-1'); 
  }
}
```

**Component.html.ts**

```
<div class="form">
  <div *ngFor="let n of numbers; let i = index">
    {{ n }} {{ i }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**ParentComponent.component.ts**

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
import {EmployeeData} from "../EmployeeData";

export abstract class ParentComponent {

  @Input('EmployeeData') employeeData : EmployeeData;
  protected formElement;
  protected errorMessage : string;

  protected constructor() {
    this.errorMessage = "";
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Component } from './Component/Component.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './ParentComponent/ParentComponent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component,
    ParentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I run this, *ngFor generates 3 empty divs, with no content inside of them. I have tested this over and over and searched for possible solutions, but still no luck.

Am I just dumb and doing anything wrong?

EDIT: Updated with more code.

EDIT 2: I tried this code in another Component and it works... Are there reasons why ngFor might not work?

Comment: `numbers` in your class can't be private, remove the `private` keyword and it should work

Comment: @peinearydevelopment The result is the same if I remove the private.

Comment: Only other thing I see is that in your `ngOnInit`, it should be `console.log(this.numbers);`. Maybe you're getting an error? Your above code works as seen here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywyeng

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Sorry that was a typo while writing the post. I do include the "this" in my original code. I really only include that in the post, just so I could mention that it prints the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is obviously wrong with your code is that `numbers` is private. Remove that access modifier.

I produced [a little codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBxgyO) showing you a working example with your code.

Comment: I don't think private affects it, as I have removed it in my original code, and nothing has changed. I can't imagine why code isn't working, while the codepen code is.

Comment: Can you supply your entire code, including your `ParentComponent`?

Comment: I changed the code in codepen. I marked `numbers` as a private class member. And it works anyway.

Comment: Yes, your `private` modifier will only be a problem when actually compiling. The codepen was to demonstrate you that there is no actual problem with the code you have presented here. That's why I am asking you to share the full code, including `ParentComponent`.

Comment: @fjc That was someone else that replied to you. I have just updated the code now.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.